# Get previous object without len(list)

Tags: python, list

How to get previous or next object with this format of code?

```
alignment = [[a,b,c],[2,3,4],[q,w,e]]

for obj in alignment:
    some code here to get previous object
```

I know how to do that with:

```
for i in range(0,len(alignment)):
    alignment[i-1][objIndex]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) :

```
alignment = [[a,b,c],[2,3,4],[q,w,e]]

for index,obj in enumerate(alignment):
    alignment[index-1] # pre
    alignment[index+1] # next
```

*Note* that as a more efficient way for accessing to `next` items and refuse of multiple indexing you can use [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) function to create an iterator object from your list (from second element to end) and access to   next elements in each iteration with `next` :

```
>>> l=[1,2,3,4]
>>> it=iter(l[1:])
>>> for i in l :
...   print i,next(it,None)
... 
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 None
```

*Note* that if you don't pass the `None` as the second argument to `next()` function it will raise a `StopIteration` error.You can also handle it with a `try-except` statement.

Also for short lists you can use `zip` function and for long lists [`itertools.izip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) (`zip` in python 3):

```
>>> for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]):
...   print i,j
... 
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

`zip(l,l[1:])` will give you the following pairs of items :

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

and in the loop you can use `i` as the current item then `j` will be the next item or use `j` as the current then `i` will be the previous!:)

Comment: This will regard the last item to be prior to the first, and cause an error when not finding a next item after the last.

Comment: @YannVernier Indeed and its why is passed the `None` to `next` function.

Comment: Why *for short lists*? The `zip()` solution is the best option in all cases. If you are in 2.x where `zip()` isn't lazy, using `itertools.izip()` is the solution.

Comment: @Lattyware No `zip` is efficient for short and for long list `itertools` is the best i wanted to add this after that but seems that i have forgot it! O_0 ... thanks for reminding!

Comment: `zip_longest()` in Python 3 is not the equivalent to `izip()` - in Python 3 `zip()` is lazy (has the behaviour of `izip()` in 2.x). `zip_longest()` is if you want a value with the items from the longer iterable, instead of stopping as the shortest one runs out.

Comment: @Lattyware Yeah indeed! just a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different options depending on what your use for the neighbour entry is. For instance, if you only want to process pairs, and not modify the list:

```
for left,right in zip(somelist[:-1], somelist[1:]):
  pass
```

Or if you need to keep the prior entry as a reference:

```
prev = None
for item in somelist:
  pass
  prev = item
```

`None` here is used in place of a prior item for the first, similar to how it's used for the next item after the last in Kasra's iter()-based example.

Comment: Just saw this question, and this was the first method that popped into my head...

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, obj in enumerate(alignment):
    alignment[index-1]
```

The loop will give the index and object the previous object can be accessed by the (current index - 1) whereas the next by (current index + 1)